# getString() causes null pointer reference in class that extends application

Tags: java, android

I have a class that extends application.  I need to get a string from the strings.xml file.

I'm using this class to manage global state, so it is being loaded via the manifest.

Upon load, the getString() generates a null pointer reference.

How can I access the strings from this class?

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

public MyApp() {
    try {
        String apiurl = getString(R.string.api_url);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("MyApp", e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a method `getString()` inside your class `MyApp` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `onCreate` function rather than use a constructor.

So...

```
public void onCreate() {
   try {
      String apiurl = getString(R.string.api_url);
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       Log.v("MyApp", e.toString());
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()